# Jump to current cursor position in Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos

How do I jump to the current cursor position in Xcode?

For example, I am coding at line 748. I scroll up to line 35 to look at a part of my code. The cursor is still at line 748. Is there a keyboard shortcut to jump back down to where the cursor is?

Answer (score 0):

Hit the spacebar.

Delete the space if you want.